# How to close Android application under test using ant?

Tags: android, ant, android-emulator, automation

To launch the application I am doing:

```
<target name="run">
    <exec executable="adb">
        <arg value="shell"/>
        <arg value="am"/>
        <arg value="start"/>
        <arg value="-a"/>
        <arg value="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <arg value="-n"/>
        <arg value="com.go.ring.demo1/.RootActivity"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
```

However, I want to close this application. What is the ant code to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `kill`:

```
am kill: kill all processes associated with <PACKAGE>
```

or `force-stop`:

```
am force-stop: force stop everything associated with <PACKAGE>
```

In general, you should do:

```
adb shell
```

and while in shell, do `am` without parameters - this will show all am's options and switches.

Comment: Worked successfully!!.. thnk u so much for the help. :D